# How to instantiate an ARSCNView

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, arkit

I would like to use ARKit to calculate the amount of ambient light that is in the current video frame. However after creating an ARSCNView object when I retrieve the current frame it returns a null value.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public class EyeAlignmentUICameraPreview : UIView, IAVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate
{

void Initialize()
{
      CaptureSession = new CaptureSession();
      PreviewLayer = new AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(CaptureSession)
      {
            Frame = Bounds,
            VideoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.ResizeAspectFill
      };
      var device = AVCaptureDevice.GetDefaultDevice(AVCaptureDeviceType.BuiltInTelephotoCamera, AVMediaType.Video, AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back);

     ARSCNView SceneView = new ARSCNView();
     // frame is null after this line is executed
     var frame = SceneView.Session.CurrentFrame;
}
}
```

Comment: You didn't create a session configuration for ARSCNView, and the ARFrame is `A video image and position tracking information captured as part of an AR session.`. So, the frame will have value when the video is showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Update my comment to answer for more details.*

[**ARFrame**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arframe)

> A video image and position tracking information captured as part of an AR session.

[**currentFrame**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsession/2865621-currentframe)

> The video frame image, with associated AR scene information, most recently captured by the session.

According to these Apple ARKit Documentations, the `currentFrame` will have value when the ARSession get the video and associated AR scene information. **So, we have to run the session at first.**

To run the [ARSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsession), we need a session configuration:

> Running a session requires a session configuration: an instance of the ARConfiguration class, or its subclass ARWorldTrackingConfiguration. These classes determine how ARKit tracks a device's position and motion relative to the real world, and thus affect the kinds of AR experiences you can create.

Thus, the code snippet for ARSession running is like this:

```
public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
{
    base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

    //Create a session configuration
    var configuration = new ARWorldTrackingConfiguration
    {
        PlaneDetection = ARPlaneDetection.Horizontal,
        LightEstimationEnabled = true
    };

    // Run the view's session
    SceneView.Session.Run(configuration, ARSessionRunOptions.ResetTracking);
}
```